# Flex - Transparent Tree component

Tags: apache-flex, tree, transparent

I'm using a tree component to show a menu, but I need the background to be transparent.

How can I do this? :)
I could make a new "skin" or create a new class (using the old tree) where I remove the background, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Any help would be great!

Thanks,

Comment: Both your approaches seem viable.  Why don't you try one of them, and come back to us with your specific problem.

Comment: I'll do that ;) I did have a look through Tree.as, but it was about 4000 lines. Was hoping someone knew it from the top of their head :)

Comment: And it looks like there are set colors for each individual row, and for highlighting and such... Was hoping for an easier way to do this :)

Comment: 4,000 lines of code seems small to me for a Flex Framework component. :-)  I'm glad you found the solution.  And I'm glad it was simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my fault.. I did searches, and found very little information about this.

setting contentBackgroundAlpha to 0 does the trick (in the tree component).